# Sum cells based on vertical and horizontal criteria in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet which is similar in structure to what you can see on this spreadsheet.

[image: Spreadsheet]

I tried several ways to calculate YTD figures of the different categories but failed. What formula should I put in cell C14 to get all fruits summed up between Week 1 and Week 5?

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C3:L9,(C2:L2<=C12)*(B3:B9=C13))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I can't add a comment, but Scott Craner's answer only gives the total for week 5, not a YTD. To add the totals for each week up to and including week 5, change the first equal sign to <=:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C3:L9,(C2:L2<=C12)*(B3:B9=C13))
```

Comment: In that way you can propose an edit to Scott's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this is to have intermediate SUMIF formulas on a separate row, and then have cell C14 simply be the sum of those.

So for example, put in cell C10:
=SUMIF($B3:$B9,"Fruit",C3:C9)

Then drag that formula across to column L, and put in cell C14:
=SUM(C10:L10)

If you don't want to expose the sub-totals to people viewing the sheet, you can hide row 10.